# Can I use Plesk to grant site access to more than one user per site and multiple sites per user?

Tags: plesk, users, management

I am new to Parallels Plesk control panel and I have the reseller account of it. Here I want to ask about user management.

Let say I have website A, B, C, D, and E hosted on my dedicated server. Is it possible that I create a few user accounts to manage website for file & database management like:

- User 1 manage Website A, B, and C.
- User 2 manage Website A, D, and E.
- User 3 manage Website B, C, and E.

Is it possible to do that? If can how?